# Using ng-model to display input value in p element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a slider module called `slick`. I have a tab heading which tracks and displays the index of the slide so the user can see. Issue is that the tab heading slides with each slide as that tab is inside the carousel (obviously).

I moved the tab heading out of the slide, and planned to display to use `ng-model` and `ng-value` to bind the data to an element outside of the slide. Like so:

```
<div>
     <p>Blue Renewal {{vm.slide.number}} of {{$ctrl.blueRenewals.length}}</p>
</div>
<slick data="$ctrl.phaseArr" >
     <div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.phaseArr">
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slide.number" ng-value="{{$index + 1}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</slick>
```

And in the .js:

```
vm.slide = {
    number: '1'
}
```

***Question***

Why isn't the value from the input binding to the p element outside of the slick carousel?

Comment: Don't use ng-model and ng-value together. Remove ng-value from input element. ng-model is already assign value to your input

Comment: But it is the value of the index of the slide I need to display in the p element?

Comment: You can not use ng-model with `p`. ng-model is for user-input elements like inputbox, checkbox, select etc

Comment: Yeah, but I can bind the value of an user-input element to other other elements though can't I?

Comment: We don't see much code here. Are you explicitly putting `vm` on the $scope in your controller?

Comment: Oh god I just realised what I did

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say with so little code to go on, but I suspect you're encountering a scope issue.

There are at least two, probably at least three levels of scope in play here. Your heading is in your controller accessing properties of its scope. So when you bind to `vm.slide.number` it's looking on your scope. The 'slick' component likely creates a scope of its own, which may be where `vm` comes from. If that's the case, your view (on the parent of slick's scope) can't see properties on it.

(The ngRepeat also creates child scopes, but I don't think that's the problem.)